# MYSQL SELECT first and last row WHERE multiple condition

Tags: mysql

First table:

```
Time    |  Name   |  Value   
10:00   |    A    |   1
08:00   |    A    |   1    <-- This is NEW 'first' time (because now it has new value)
01:00   |    A    |  null  <-- This is 'last' time
23:00   |    A    |  null
19:00   |    A    |  0
16:00   |    A    |  0
10:00   |    A    |  0    <--This is 'first' time of value 0
```

What I want to get is every first, and last time

The logic is:
SELECT the FIRST A's 'time' WHERE value is not null, the last 'time' BEFORE the next A's VALUE is not null

The result:

```
Time    |  Name   |  Value   
01:00   |    A    |  null  <-- This is 'last' time
10:00   |    A    |  0    <--This is 'first' time of value 0
```

No other column can be use. This table is just a collection of time, name and value.

How? I have the logic, but it's too complicated. I hope it's okay for asking this. Thank you!

Comment: what's your expected output? still a bit unclear to me

Comment: I want "10:00 | A | 0" and "01:00 | A | null"

Comment: What's your primary key (time,value) presumably? And edit your question to clearly show the desired result

Comment: Do you have a column which can be used to order records within a given `Value` ?

Comment: There's no way to determine which row is last/latest unless you have  a `primary key` or `timestamp` instead of `time`

Comment: @1000111 is there anyway to pick the row before the first value not null occurrence?